# Spring Social fails to connect with facebook

Tags: java, facebook, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am using quite basic setting to connect facebook using spring boot and spring social, but I am getting a warning in the log and no other details:

```
2015-11-01 09:26:34.574  WARN 69742 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.s.connect.web.ConnectController      : Exception while handling OAuth2 callback ((#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.). Redirecting to facebook connection status page.
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserLoginOauth {

    private Facebook facebook;

    @Inject
    public UserLoginOauth(Facebook facebook) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fb")
    public String connectFacebook(Model model) {
        try {
            if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
                return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and my property file:

```
spring.social.facebook.appId=XXX
spring.social.facebook.appSecret=YYY
spring.social.auto_connection_views=true
```

When I go to my /fb url, I am redirect to http://localhost:8181/connect/facebook with a button to connect to facebook

On clicking that button, it calls http://localhost:8181/connect/facebook and then redirect to https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=WWW and again it redirects to http://localhost:8181/connect/facebook?code=ddd&state=GGG

But this redirect fails with the warning message "Exception while handling OAuth2 callback", with no other information.

I enabled spring social logs, and put it below incase it helps!

```
2015-11-09 15:07:38.130 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/connect/facebook]
2015-11-09 15:07:38.131 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /connect/facebook
2015-11-09 15:07:38.131 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connect(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)]
2015-11-09 15:07:38.131 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'connectController'
2015-11-09 15:07:38.131 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2015-11-09 15:07:38.132 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: unnamed; URL [https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8181%2Fconnect%2Ffacebook&state=SSS]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-11-09 15:07:38.132 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2015-11-09 15:07:38.132 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
2015-11-09 15:07:38.132 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2015-11-09 15:07:42.007 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/connect/facebook]
2015-11-09 15:07:42.007 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /connect/facebook
2015-11-09 15:07:42.008 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.oauth2Callback(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)]
2015-11-09 15:07:42.008 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'connectController'
2015-11-09 15:07:42.008 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/connect/facebook] is: -1
2015-11-09 15:07:42.008 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2015-11-09 15:07:42.009 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Created POST request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token"
2015-11-09 15:07:42.009 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Setting request Accept header to [application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, application/json, application/*+json]
2015-11-09 15:07:42.009 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{client_id=[AAA], client_secret=[BBB], code=[CCC], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:8181/connect/facebook], grant_type=[authorization_code]}] using [org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter@16aa8eeb]
2015-11-09 15:07:42.554 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token" resulted in 200 (OK)
2015-11-09 15:07:42.555 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading [interface java.util.Map] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@53ab366e]
2015-11-09 15:07:42.559 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Created GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?fields=id%2Cabout%2Cage_range%2Caddress%2Cbio%2Cbirthday%2Ccontext%2Ccover%2Ccurrency%2Cdevices%2Ceducation%2Cemail%2Cfavorite_athletes%2Cfavorite_teams%2Cfirst_name%2Cgender%2Chometown%2Cinspirational_people%2Cinstalled%2Cinstall_type%2Cis_verified%2Clanguages%2Clast_name%2Clink%2Clocale%2Clocation%2Cmeeting_for%2Cmiddle_name%2Cname%2Cname_format%2Cpolitical%2Cquotes%2Cpayment_pricepoints%2Crelationship_status%2Creligion%2Csecurity_settings%2Csignificant_other%2Csports%2Ctest_group%2Ctimezone%2Cthird_party_id%2Cupdated_time%2Cverified%2Cvideo_upload_limits%2Cviewer_can_send_gift%2Cwebsite%2Cwork"
2015-11-09 15:07:42.584 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
2015-11-09 15:07:42.695 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?fields=id%2Cabout%2Cage_range%2Caddress%2Cbio%2Cbirthday%2Ccontext%2Ccover%2Ccurrency%2Cdevices%2Ceducation%2Cemail%2Cfavorite_athletes%2Cfavorite_teams%2Cfirst_name%2Cgender%2Chometown%2Cinspirational_people%2Cinstalled%2Cinstall_type%2Cis_verified%2Clanguages%2Clast_name%2Clink%2Clocale%2Clocation%2Cmeeting_for%2Cmiddle_name%2Cname%2Cname_format%2Cpolitical%2Cquotes%2Cpayment_pricepoints%2Crelationship_status%2Creligion%2Csecurity_settings%2Csignificant_other%2Csports%2Ctest_group%2Ctimezone%2Cthird_party_id%2Cupdated_time%2Cverified%2Cvideo_upload_limits%2Cviewer_can_send_gift%2Cwebsite%2Cwork" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
2015-11-09 15:07:42.696 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.s.f.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler    : Error from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.","type":"OAuthException","code":3,"fbtrace_id":"HB0Fe9k\/zM1"}}
2015-11-09 15:07:42.696 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.s.f.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler    : Facebook error: 
2015-11-09 15:07:42.696 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.s.f.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler    :    CODE        : 3
2015-11-09 15:07:42.696 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.s.f.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler    :    TYPE        : OAuthException
2015-11-09 15:07:42.696 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.s.f.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler    :    SUBCODE     : null
2015-11-09 15:07:42.696 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.s.f.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler    :    MESSAGE     : (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.
2015-11-09 15:07:42.696 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.s.f.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler    :    USER TITLE  : null
2015-11-09 15:07:42.719 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.s.f.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler    :    USER MESSAGE: null
2015-11-09 15:07:42.719  WARN 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.s.connect.web.ConnectController      : Exception while handling OAuth2 callback ((#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.). Redirecting to facebook connection status page.
2015-11-09 15:07:42.719 DEBUG 14198 --- [nio-8181-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: unnamed; URL [/connect/facebook]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Comment: @kmanish007 did you set any value at developers.facebook.com -> my apps -> settings -> advanced -> "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" ?

Comment: Yes I have set it as localhost:8181 (my port number)

Comment: Are you using the same URLCallback value in all the steps involved?

Comment: There is none of my code, spring social is doing everything, so yes all urlcallbacks are same code.

Answer (score 0):

---

> extend two of spring social class ConnectResource & ConnectSupport and
>   override the callback_url or aplicationUrl your problem will be
>   resolve

---